# Can your help me please with a product

Tags: analysis

Excuse me, but I have no idea about this product. Can you help me? Thank you. $$\prod_{k=3}^{n}(1-\frac{1}{k})$$($n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus\{1,2\}$)

Answer (score 2):

Writing some factors $$\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdots \frac{n-1}{n},$$ we will see the answer: $$\frac{2}{n}.$$

Comment: nice observed :-) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Let $$u_n=\prod_{k=3}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right).$$
Then,
$$\log(u_n)=\sum_{k=3}^n\log\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)=\sum_{k=3}^n\log(k-1)-\log(k),$$
which is a telescopic sum.

Answer (score 1):

it's a telescopic product once you write it as : $\Pi_{k=3}^{n} \frac{k-1}{k}= \frac{2}{n} $ , if you don't see it you can prove it by induction , or use $\ln$ , let $u_{k}=k$ ,  the above product is   $\Pi_{k=3}^{n} \frac{u_{k-1}}{u_{k}}$ , hence $\ln(\Pi_{k=3}^{n} \frac{u_{k-1}}{u_{k}})=\sum_{k=3}^{n} \ln(u_{k-1})-\ln(u_{k})=\ln(u_{2})-\ln(u_{n})$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$$\prod_{k=3}^{n}(1-\frac{1}{k})=\prod_{k=3}^{n}\frac{k-1}{k}=\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{4}{5} \cdots \frac{n-1}{n}$$